# asp.net datagrid findcontrol returns null for textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

in ASP.Net datagrid I placed one dropdown and a textbox (multiline). I needs to read those values in a loop. I am getting the reference object of dropdown using findControl method but when I am trying for textbox its returns null.

Here is my aspx code

```
.....
 <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList 
                    ID="HeaderDropDown" Runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack="True" 
                     OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList 
                    ID="ItemDropDown" Runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
          <asp:TemplateColumn >
          <HeaderTemplate>
            Details
            </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDetails" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

        </ItemTemplate>       
         </asp:TemplateColumn>
...............
```

The C# code is

```
 for (int i = 1; i < DataGrid1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList lst = DataGrid1.Items[i].Cells[1].FindControl("ItemDropDown") as DropDownList;
            String value = lst.SelectedValue;
            String StaffId = DataGrid1.Items[i].Cells[0].Text;
            TextBox txt= DataGrid1.Items[i].Cells[2].FindControl("txtDetaills") as TextBox;
         }
```

I am getting the **lst** object correctly, but **txt** always returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
TextBox txt= DataGrid1.Items[i].Cells[2].FindControl("txtDetaills") as TextBox;
```

Should be:

```
TextBox txt= DataGrid1.Items[i].Cells[2].FindControl("txtDetails") as TextBox;
```

Therefore, `txtDetaills` should be `txtDetails`

Answer (score 1):

`txtDetails`, not `txtDetaills` - too many Ls!