# Checkboxes in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, datagrid

I have a GridView containing a column with checkboxes. The header template has a a checkbox to select all the other checkboxes in the column.

When I tick and do an event, I am getting this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on this line:

```
ifchecked = DirectCast(item.FindControl("ckTransferItem"), CheckBox).Checked
```

DataGrid Code:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="Dgcabinet" runat="server" CssClass="datagrids psLink" Width="100%" BorderStyle="None"
ForeColor="Transparent" GridLines="Horizontal" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" AllowPaging="True"
AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="200">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="datagrids psLink"></ItemStyle>
    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" CssClass="datagridsHeader"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="file_pk"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="file_pk" SortExpression="file_pk" HeaderText="&amp;nbsp;File Number">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="file_subject"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="file_subject" SortExpression="file_subject" HeaderText="&amp;nbsp;File Name">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="cab_pk"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="cab_pk" SortExpression="cab_pk" HeaderText="&amp;nbsp;Storage Number">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="comp_part"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="comp_part" SortExpression="comp_part" HeaderText="&amp;nbsp;Compartment No.">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="dept_pk"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="dept_code" SortExpression="dept_code" HeaderText="&amp;nbsp;Department Code">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="locationno" SortExpression="locationno" HeaderText="&amp;nbsp;Storage Location">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Tick to Transfer">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ckTransferItem" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="datagridsFooter psLink" Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Button Event Handler:

```
  Private Sub btnbulktransfer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnbulktransfer.Click
    'get number of rows in datagrid
    Dim rowcount As Integer = Dgcabinet.Items.Count
    Dim itemrow As Integer = 0
    Dim item As DataGridItem
    Dim ifchecked As Boolean = False
    Dim getcompartment As Integer
    Dim getnewstate As Integer
    Dim getlocation As Integer
    Dim statetocomment As String
    Dim lbresult As Boolean = False
    Dim liUserRoleId As Integer
    Dim liUserId As Integer
    Dim switch As Boolean = False
    Dim linewdepartment As Integer
    Dim licurrentdepartment As Integer
    Dim lioldstates As Integer
    Dim listateid As Integer
    Dim lsImriehelRepository As String
    lioldstates = ddloldstates.SelectedValue


    licurrentdepartment = ddldepts.SelectedValue

    liUserRoleId = Convert.ToInt64(lcPrimitives.GetSessionCache("_USERROLE_ID"))
    liUserId = Convert.ToInt64(lcPrimitives.GetSessionCache("_USER_ID"))


    getlocation = ddllocation.SelectedValue
    getcompartment = ddlstorage.SelectedValue
    getnewstate = ddlnewstates.SelectedValue
    statetocomment = ddlnewstates.Items(ddlnewstates.SelectedIndex).Text
    linewdepartment = BLeRecords.getFileDepartment(getcompartment)
    listateid = ddldepts.SelectedValue

    'check if storage is in the imriehel repository
    lsImriehelRepository = [Global]._eRecordsPortalConstants.eRecordsCONST_ToImriehelRepository
    If linewdepartment = lsImriehelRepository Then
        linewdepartment = licurrentdepartment
    End If

    'check that all 'transfer to' dropdown options are selected
    If (getlocation = 0) Then
        lblError.Visible = True
        lblError.Text = "!Error. Please check location dropdown."
    ElseIf (getcompartment = 0) Then
        lblError.Visible = True
        lblError.Text = "!Error. Please check Storage dropdown."
    ElseIf (getnewstate = 0) Then
        lblError.Visible = True
        lblError.Text = "!Error. Please check Status dropdown."
    Else
        Dim fileIDs As ArrayList = New ArrayList
        Dim department As Integer
        ClearMessages()




        For itemrow = 0 To rowcount - 1

            Dim cb As CheckBox = item.Cells(11).FindControl("ckTransferItem")
            If cb.Checked Then
                ifchecked = True
            Else
                ifchecked = False
            End If


            department = Integer.Parse(item.Cells(8).Text())

            If ifchecked Then
                Dim filenumber As String = (item.Cells(0).Text())
                fileIDs.Add(filenumber)
                switch = True
            End If
        Next

        'check if tickbox are ticked. If not returns error.
        If switch = False Then
            lblError.Visible = True
            lblError.Text = "!Error. Please check tick box"
        Else
            lbresult = BLeRecords.updateBulkTransferBatch(fileIDs, getcompartment, linewdepartment, getnewstate, statetocomment, liUserId, listateid)

            If lbresult = True Then
                lblmessage.Text = "File transfer succesful"
                lblmessage.Visible = True
                DisplaySortedData("", lioldstates, licurrentdepartment, False)
            Else
                lblError.Visible = True
                lblError.Text = "!Error. File transfer Failed. Contact Administrator"
            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

This is what I tried but I still get the same error:

```
For Each dgItem As DataGridItem In Dgcabinet.Items

    If (dgItem.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) OrElse (dgItem.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
    
        ifchecked = DirectCast(dgItem.FindControl("ckTransferItem"), CheckBox).Checked
        department = Integer.Parse(dgItem.Cells(8).Text)

End If

Next
```

Can anyone explain why?

If the checkbox is checked it should be set to True no?

Comment: Please post your vb.net code responsible for finding and updating checkbox status .What is  `item` in above code ? From above code I can tell it is unable to find the control and returning null.

Comment: @CoderofCode Hi, sorry.. I edited main question to include the button's event handler code. `item` is a datagrid item

Comment: How can I do that? This happens either when I check one box, or check all.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the `ItemType` of `datagrid` item before finding control . In most probable cases the first item or row is always the `headertype` and it try to find that checkbox in header and that's why it returns the null.

```
  If (item.ItemType ==  ListItemType.Item) || 
         (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
        ifchecked = DirectCast(item.Cells[11].FindControl("ckTransferItem"), CheckBox).Checked
        //Your other code  
  End If
```

To read more about [ItemType here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagriditem.itemtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can also replace all for loop code with the foreach loop

```
     foreach(DataGridItem item in Dgcabinet.Items)
     {
        if((item.ItemType ==  ListItemType.Item) || 
           (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
          {
             ifchecked = DirectCast(item.Cells[11].FindControl("ckTransferItem"), CheckBox).Checked
             department = int.Parse(item.Cells(8).Text())
             If ifchecked Then
                fileIDs.Add((item.Cells(0).Text()))
                switch = True
             End If
          }
     }
```

Comment: I still get the same error. See updated answer for the code that I have tried.

Comment: Try the update . Just make sure the Cell[11] where `11` is the column number congaing checkbox starting from 0 base index.

Comment: The problem is that the checkbox control is not found. I tried `Dim cb As CheckBox = item.FindControl("ckTransferItem")` and the value of cb remains 'Nothing'

Comment: Yes I know that's why try `Dim cb As CheckBox = item.Cells[11].FindControl("ckTransferItem")`

Comment: Still the same error. I tried calling it by finding the element name from the HTML source (as I thought it was changing the name on running the app) and it still couldn't find it. Maybe this is not possible when using a DataGrid?

Comment: No it is possible can you post your new code ? And check if you are making any typo or anything Here is another question same as yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119573/asp-net-datagrid-findcontrol-returns-null-for-textbox

Comment: Hi, I'm sure there are no typos. Re-edited post to include new code.

Comment: Use the debugger and see if there control present in that cell.

Comment: And you are not assigning anything to the item please correct that assign the item to datagriditem and then also check with the if it's type and make sure it is `(item.ItemType ==  ListItemType.Item) || 
           (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))`

Comment: Hi, I removed the 'select all' although I made no alterations from the backend and it's working, but I have to tick all the items manually. It seems the 'select all' feature is causing the problem.